# Plot Quiver Function

Tags: python

I am trying to create a quiver plot from a NetCDF file in Python using this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import netCDF4 as Dataset 

ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset('30JUNE2012_0300UTC.cdf', 'r')
dbZ = ncfile.variables['MAXDBZF']
data = dbZ[0,0]
U = ncfile.variables['UNEW'][:]
V = ncfile.variables['VNEW'][:]
x, y= np.arange(0,2*np.pi,.2), np.arange(0,2*np.pi,.2)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

plt.quiver(X,Y,U,V)

plt.show()
```

and I am getting the following errors

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-b449c540a7ea> in <module>()
     11 X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
     12 
---> 13 plt.quiver(X,Y,U,V)
     14 
     15 plt.show()

/Users/felishalawrence/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in quiver(*args, **kw)
   3152         ax.hold(hold)
   3153     try:
-> 3154         ret = ax.quiver(*args, **kw)
   3155         draw_if_interactive()
   3156     finally:

/Users/felishalawrence/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in quiver(self, *args, **kw)
   4162         if not self._hold:
   4163             self.cla()
-> 4164         q = mquiver.Quiver(self, *args, **kw)
   4165 
   4166         self.add_collection(q, autolim=True)

/Users/felishalawrence/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/quiver.pyc in __init__(self, ax, *args, **kw)
    415         """
    416         self.ax = ax
--> 417         X, Y, U, V, C = _parse_args(*args)
    418         self.X = X
    419         self.Y = Y

/Users/felishalawrence/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/quiver.pyc in _parse_args(*args)
    377         nr, nc = 1, U.shape[0]
    378     else:
--> 379         nr, nc = U.shape
    380     if len(args) == 2:  # remaining after removing U,V,C
    381         X, Y = [np.array(a).ravel() for a in args]

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: `nr, nc = U.shape` tries to unpack two items from `U.shape` into the two separate names `nr` and `nc`. *"too many values to unpack"* means that there are **more than two** on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

`ValueError: too many values to unpack` is because the line `379` of your program is trying to assign two variables (`nr`, `nc`) from `U.shape` when there are not enough variables to assign these values to.

Look above on line `377` - that is correctly assigning two values (`1` and `U.shape[0]` to `nr` and `nc` but line `379` has only a `U.shape` object to assign to two variables.  If there are more than 2 values in `U.shape` you will get this error.  It was made clear that `U.shape` is actually a tuple with at least two values which means that this code would work as-is as long as there are an equal amount of values to assign to the variables (in this case two).  I would print out the value of `U.shape` and determine that it holds the expected values and quantity of values.  If you `U.shape` can return two or more values then your code will need to learn how to adapt to this.  For example if you find that `U.shape` is a tuple of 3 values then you will need 3 variables to hold those values like so:

`nr, nc, blah = U.shape`

Consider the following:

```
a,b,c = ["a","b","c"] #works

print a
print b 
print c

a, b = ["a","b","c"] #will result in error because 3 values are trying to be assigned to only 2 variables
```

The results from the above code:

```
a
b
c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "None", line 7, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

So you see it's just a matter of having enough values to assign to all of the variables that are requesting a value.

Comment: *"only has 1 value to give so one variable will not have a value"* - not true; in that case, the message would be `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`. The message the OP is getting, `ValueError: too many values to unpack`, means that there are **too many** - `shape` is e.g. a tuple containing more than two separate values.

Comment: You are correct and I believe that is what I was trying to say.  There are too many values that are trying to be assigned to not enough variables. I will edit the line to avoid confusion.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Probably more useful to solve future problems rather then author's but still:
The problem was likely that the netcdf file had a time dimension, therefore U and V where 3 dimensional arrays - you should choose the time slice or aggregate the data across the time dimension.